# How can I update values in database table using an upgrade script?

Tags: database, magento-1, sql, upgrade-script

I am trying to UPDATE values inside of the directory_country table using a data-upgrade script but hit a brick wall with the syntax for updating a table using this method as I am trying to avoid using direct SQL.

Here's what I have so far but it doesn't work at the moment:

```
<?php 
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->run("
UPDATE `{$installer->getTable('directory_country')}` SET (`country_id`, `iso2_code`, `iso3_code`, `restriction_set`) WHERE
('GG', 'GG', 'GGY', '0'),('AD', 'AD', 'ADY', '7'),('AI', 'AI', 'AIA', '7'),('AG', 'AG', 'ATG', '7');
");

$installer->endSetup();
```

Could anyone suggest the best way to do this  please?

Comment: If you try to avoid SQL, stop thinking in tables and database and start thinking in models. How would you change the models associated with these entries? Works the same way I setup scripts.

Comment: @Melvyn thanks for your feedback but I must admit that it hasn't help me to move any closer to how I update these tables... Can you provide an example please?

Answer (score 2):

Try working with objects and `save` methods.
Define an array with the data you need updating

```
$config = array(
    'GG' => array(
        'iso2_code' => 'GG', 
        'iso3_code' => 'GGY', 
        'restriction_set' => 0
    ),
    'AD' => array(
        'iso2_code' => 'AD', 
        'iso3_code' => 'ADY', 
        'restriction_set' => 7
    ),
    //add the rest of the data here following the same pattern
);
```

Then loop through the array, load the country, set the data and save

```
foreach ($config as $key => $data) {
     $country = Mage::getModel('directory/country')->load($key);
     $country->addData($data);
     $country->save();
}
```

I know that using `load` and `save` in loops is not the best way to do it, but since this is an upgrade script that should run only once you should be OK with it.